# Youtube api thumbail size ordering changed?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api

This just happened and I'd like someone to confirm it before I go changing all my site code...

Using Zend framework to get YouTube videos and then `VideoEntry` and later `getVideoThumbnails()` the original thumbnail size array used to return in size order (smallest to biggest, an example in in this blog: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/)

But testing a site just now, it seems they have put the biggest to the beginning, a dump of `getVideoThumbnails()` now gives:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'time' => string '00:00:59' (length=8)
      'height' => string '240' (length=3)
      'width' => string '320' (length=3)
      'url' => string '.....' (length=39)
  1 => 
    array
      'time' => string '00:00:29.500' (length=12)
      'height' => string '90' (length=2)
      'width' => string '120' (length=3)
      'url' => string '...' (length=39)
  2 => 
    array
      'time' => string '00:00:59' (length=8)
      'height' => string '90' (length=2)
      'width' => string '120' (length=3)
      'url' => string '...' (length=39)
  3 => 
    array
      'time' => string '00:01:28.500' (length=12)
      'height' => string '90' (length=2)
      'width' => string '120' (length=3)
      'url' => string '...' (length=39)
```

Can someone confirm this is correct or is my code playing up somewhere? I've searched for a notice stating the change but found nothing. If they have changed it, how can I sort this array by 'height' value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array by height.

Example:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return ($a['height'] > $b['height']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```